# Another こと usage question

Tags: grammar, translation, nominalization

I'm trying to translate the sentence "Food is an easy topic for me to write about" to Japanese, but I'm struggling. Some thoughts / questions:

(1) I know could say "Writing about food is easy":「食べ物について書くことはやさしいです。」. However, I feel like some of the nuance is lost, i.e. the implication that there are other topics that are difficult to write about.

Separately, can「の」replace「こと」in this sentence, since it is not immediately followed by「です」？ I know only「こと」can be used if 「です」immediately follows it, but am unclear if that applies when the nominalized verb is the topic of a「です」sentence.

(2) Am I correct that「こと」is preferred (but not mandatory) over「の」in this context, since there is no immediacy?

(3) My attempts so far:

「食べ物はやさしい題について書くことです」- I suspect this comes out as "Food is writing about an easy topic".

「食べ物は書きやすい題です」- Is this "Food is a topic that is easy to write (about)"? Do I need to add「について」somewhere?

(4) I'm not sure how to fit the "for me" part of the sentence into any of the proposed sentences above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1)(2) 食べ物について書くことはやさしいです and 食べ物について書くのはやさしいです are both okay, but yes, I feel こと is better, especially in polite and formal sentences.

(3)(4) Among your several attempts, 食べ物は書きやすい題です is the best. 題 is more like *title* rather than *topic*, so let's use 話題 instead. (You can safely use 話題 even when you are not talking vocally.) To translate "for me", you can use 私[にとって](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-ni-totte/).

> 食べ物は私にとって書きやすい話題です。
>   (literally) Food is an easy-to-write topic for me.